# Can Razor Pages open the file explorer on your PC to a specific directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

My goal is not for backend manipulation of the specified directory. I only want an instance of explorer.exe to open up a to a specified share drive directory via a link from an index page and am wondering if this is even possible with Razor pages. I have searched far and wide on the internet and have found the FileExplorerOperations class, but it does not appear that one of those operations is to open file explorer for you.

I do not know where to begin with an attempt at this because so far I have not found a single method to do such, so I don't have any code examples of things I've tried. [Picture of my index page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYdVq.png)

Upon creation, a folder is created on a share drive with the same name as the Job Number. I want "Open Folder" to just open that file directory in file explorer visible to the user. Is this possible with Razor Pages?

Comment: Not possible. Can't be done.

Comment: The reason you haven't found a single method to do such is because it is not possible. Imagine the security implications if any random website could open Windows Explorer to whatever folder they wanted?

Comment: I had not thought of security implications, but that does make sense. Thank you